# Calling msync Necessary?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, centos7, centos6

After reading few articles and posts:
https://lwn.net/Articles/502612/
[mmap, msync(MS_ASYNC) and munmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26097316/mmap-msyncms-async-and-munmap)

I am kind of confused:
1. whether msync really does anything (2nd link above includes a section of a manpage to indicate it doesn't in newer kernels; tho, the first link says it does do something)
2. whether calling msync is necessary if a process might get killed or crashed (but not the OS).
3. how frequent does the kernel flush the mmapped memory back to the "disk"?

Let's say I use kernel 3.10 and 2.6.32.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

We need to be careful - your question title says "Calling msync Necessary?
" but `msync()` takes parameters complicating an answer:

1. On Linux `msync(MS_ASYNC)` is a no-op. On other OSes it may do something and of course you can call `msync()` with other parameters.
2. If you need to know whether syncing completed and you're willing to block until it has, you can use `msync(MS_SYNC)` (notice the lack the A). If [just your program crashes the Linux kernel will continue to track dirty filesystem pages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6219962/9109338).
3. This is going to depend on your filesystem and VM settings. See the `dirty_*` settings in https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt .

This question is similar to the [having linux persist memory changes to disk](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38089727/9109338) - if you need to know WHEN  your data is on stable media you will have to use a blocking call (which will trigger immediate writeback). There's no "please start syncing in the background" call on Linux.

Comment: Looks like you have duplicated the your answer by accident. Do you mind deleting one (and possibly merge any hard to notice differences)?

Comment: @maxschlepzig thank you for telling me - I have deleted the other as they were identical (I diffed them).